# ASP.NET Core Web API Lambda fails to handle request sent from SQS queue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I built a .NET 6 Core Web API project with controllers and converted it to a Lambda by adding the line below to the program.cs file;

`builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);`

I deployed to AWS lambda using the CLI. Calling the Lambda function from POSTMAN works fine but when I send message through SQS queue from AWS Console, I get the exception below.

```
2023-02-01T00:38:06.905Z    04b8dce2-d17c-5125-88d3-80b167d862bd    fail    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass26_0`2.<<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

here is the message I sent through POSTMAN and through the SQS queue:

```
{
    "nameOnCard": "Samuel Ojo",
    "cardNumber": "5256854950074930",
    "cvv": "283",
    "expiryMonth": "04",
    "expiryYear": "27",
    "postalCode": "101232",
    "billingAddress": "Lagos",
    "billingState": "Lagos",
    "billingCity": "Lagos",
    "billingCountry": "Nigeria",
    "awsSettings": {
        "topicArn": [redacted],
        "targetArn": [redacted],
        "snsTopicFilter": "VirtualCard"
    }
}
```

I also tried sending an SQS template message

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
      "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
      "body": "{\"sourceAccount\": \"0123445599\",\"destinationAccount\": \"1838494040\",\"bankCode\": \"011\",\"amount\": 200,\"awsSettings\": {\"topicArn\": [redacted],\"targetArn\": [redacted],\"snsTopicFilter\": \"FundTransfer\"}}",
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
        "SenderId": "123456789012",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "{{{md5_of_body}}}",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the content of the program.cs file;

```
using VirtualCardService.Middlewares;
using VirtualCardService.Services.Contracts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

#region Add Services to Container

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVirtualCardService, VirtualCardService.Services.Implementations.VirtualCardService>();
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);
#endregion

var app = builder.Build();

#region Configure Pipeline

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    return next();
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseMiddleware<HttpLoggerMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
#endregion

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you share the lambda function code? You function looks like written to handle the pay load coming from Api Gateway... the structure of the payload are different between the apigateway and SQS. Looks like the SQS event data is failed to convert to the apigateway event data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SamuelBabbs, can you share your solution if you found one please? Looking to solve a similar issue.

Comment: Hey @Samuel, are you able to fix this issue ?